# Can't run sh on virtual env or macOS

Tags: zsh

I can't run the sh script on virtual env or macOS

```
#!/bin/bash

# This script sets up the environment for a Flask project.

echo "Starting script..."

# Initialize virtual environment.
echo "Activating virtual environment..."
source env/bin/activate


# Define environment variables.
echo "Setting environment variables..."
export FLASK_APP=app.py
export FLASK_ENV=development

echo $FLASK_APP
echo "Script completed."
```

The result only shows the echo path but neither the source or the export commands work.

```
(base) user@xxx % sh envset.sh    
Starting script...
Activating virtual environment...
Setting environment variables...
application.py
Script completed.
(base) usser@xxx %
```

The env wasn't activated.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> (base) user@xxx % sh envset.sh
> ```

you're invoking a shell here as a child process of the terminal's shell.  a child process never changes its parent process's environment.

Instead you should `.` ([portable `source`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/309768/source-vs-why-different-behaviour)) the file which will execute its commands in the terminal's *current* shell process.  Then, the exports will be available to the terminal shell after the `source` completes:

```
(base) user@xxx % . envset.sh
```